# Spring boot MessageSource not working in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, internationalization

I am converting spring MVC to spring boot (2.0.3.RELEASE) project.

I am using this in spring boot, it works:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/locale/normal/message", "classpath:/locale/validation/message");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

I try to use spring boot auto-configuration (via `application.properties`) as below (remove the manual bean configuration above):

```
spring.messages.basename=classpath:/locale/normal/message,classpath:/locale/validation/message
```

I tried below, it doesn't work too:

```
spring.messages.basename=/locale/normal/message,/locale/validation/message
```

I read their [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) below:

```
# INTERNATIONALIZATION (MessageSourceProperties)
spring.messages.always-use-message-format=false # Whether to always apply the MessageFormat rules, parsing even messages without arguments.
spring.messages.basename=messages # Comma-separated list of basenames (essentially a fully-qualified classpath location), each following the ResourceBundle convention with relaxed support for slash based locations.
spring.messages.cache-duration= # Loaded resource bundle files cache duration. When not set, bundles are cached forever. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8 # Message bundles encoding.
spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=true # Whether to fall back to the system Locale if no files for a specific Locale have been found.
spring.messages.use-code-as-default-message=false # Whether to use the message code as the default message instead of throwing a "NoSuchMessageException". Recommended during development only.
```

I put the message properties file in the classpath:

```
src\main\resources\locale\normal
src\main\resources\locale\validation
```

I try a lot of combination, but it doesn't work, why?

The error I encounter :

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'login.timeout' for locale 'en'.
```

(I am pretty sure the message code is in my properties file for all locale.)

I am using Spring tag to load the localized message:

```
<spring:message code="${param.error}" />
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: forgot to mention, it is `2.0.3.RELEASE`

Comment: Also what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Can you please give the exception or error you are getting

Comment: updated the error message that I encountered.

Comment: For me, adding locale to basename solved the problem. E.g. `spring.messages.basename=my-messages_en`. By the way, `classpath:` prefix is useless.

Answer (score 0):

try use `#` instead `$` - `<spring:message code="#{param.error}" />`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have default messages.properties in addition to the locale specific messages.properties

Answer (score 0):

spring.messages.basename should be without leading slash:

```
spring.messages.basename=locale/normal/message,locale/validation/message
```